# format mysql timestamp using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have column named `postDate` defined as timestamp.
when i print it directly:

```
echo $result['postDate'];
```

i do get that what is stored(eg. `2011-03-16 16:48:24`)
on the other hand when i print it through date function:

```
echo date('F/j/Y',$result['postDate'])
```

i get `December/31/1969`

what am i doing wrong?

many thanks

Answer (score 65, accepted):

try this.

```
date('F/j/Y',strtotime($result['postDate']));
```

as timestamp is required, not formatted date as second parameter.
or you can also try

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(postDate) as postDateInt from myTable
```

instead of `SELECT postDate from myTable`
and then have this in your code.

```
date('F/j/Y',$result['postDateInt']);
```

Comment: Hm, well done you beat me to the punch. +1 for you. I also recommended UNIX_TIMESTAMP(). When I started my answer you only had the strtitime() but, but by the time I posted it you'd added the SQL bit as well.

Comment: Doesn't strtotime() take timezones into account when formatting, and mistakenly treat the UTC unix date string as being in the timezone set by PHP?

Answer (score 11):

The PHP [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function looks for an `int time()` as the 2nd param.  Try using [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo date('F/j/Y', strtotime($result['postDate']) );
```

Answer (score 8):

Why not format the date as needed in your MySQL query?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(postDate, '%M/%D/%Y') as date from table
```

Comment: that seems to be by far the easiest solution :D

Answer (score 1):

The PHP `date()' function expects a number for the second parameter - ie a unix timestamp.

You can convert a SQL date string (or virtually any other date string) into a timestamp in PHP by using the `strtotime()` function. At least two other answers have already suggested this.

However, I would suggest that you'd be better off getting the date out of your database in unix timestamp format in the first place. You can do this by querying using the MySQL `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function, as follows:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mydatefield) AS mydatefield_timestamp FROM mytable
```

..obviously, replacing the field and table names as appropriate.

Then you will get the date in timestamp format in your returned dataset in PHP, which you can pass directly into the `date()` function as follows:

```
echo date('F/j/Y',$result['mydatefield_timestamp']);
```

Hope that helps.